# How to identify network "name" using Win32_NetworkAdapter or similar?

Tags: delphi, wmi

I am looking for a way to identify the value that appears in the "Status" field of the "Network Connections" dialog i.e.

[image]

Using Win32_NetworkAdapter, it appears most of the other information presented here could be taken from this source, but the Status member is seemingly not populated as far as I can tell. Any idea where I might be able to find it. As you can see from the screen shot, my need is to pick up on the name of the mobile / cell provider of a 3G network connection.

**Update**: Added this image after DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder suggestion

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a type library that will help you to get this value:-

[Delphi Wmi Class Generator](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-wmi-class-generator/wiki/WbemScripting_TLB)

This should help you to get what you want.